# Correct syntax for highchart API yAxis label style in coffeescript?

Tags: api, syntax, highcharts, coffeescript, dashing

Javascript/Coffeescript newb here. I have recently been fiddling with a highcharts dual meter api in coffeescript. I'm trying to change change the style of my labels (i.e. color, font-size). I've looked at examples in the highchart website ([Highchart API Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.labels.style)) by translating javascript to coffeescript can be a bit finicky. The syntax below appears to be incorrect and I was just wondering what's the correct syntax for styling labels.

Coffeescript:

`@chart = undefined 
  labels = {0: '0s', 5: '0.5s', 10: '1s', 15: '10s', 20: '20s'}`

.

```
yAxis: [{
      min: 0
      max: 20
      minorTickPosition: 'outside'
      tickPosition: 'outside'
      minorTickLength: 13
      tickLength: 15

      labels: 
        enabled: true
        formatter: -> labels[@value]`
        style:
          'font-size': '20px'
          'color': '#00ff00'`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used HighCharts, but I can help with Coffeescript syntax.

The CSS object from the docs you linked to would look like this in Coffee:

```
style =
  color: '#6D869F'
  fontWeight: 'bold'
```

The yAxis array you posted shouldn't have that first curly bracket and needs the last square brack. It should look like this:

```
yAxis: [
  min: 0
  max: 20
  minorTickPosition: 'outside'
  tickPosition: 'outside'
  minorTickLength: 13
  tickLength: 15
  labels: 
    enabled: true
    formatter: -> labels[@value]
    style:
      'font-size': '20px'
      'color': '#00ff00'
]
```

That will give you an array with an object inside.

If you need an array with multiple objects you can use this:

```
yAxis: [
      {
      min: 0
      max: 20
      minorTickPosition: 'outside'
      tickPosition: 'outside'
      minorTickLength: 13
      tickLength: 15
      labels: 
        enabled: true
        formatter: -> labels[@value]
        style:
          'font-size': '20px'
          'color': '#00ff00'
     }
     {
      min: 0
      max: 20
      minorTickPosition: 'outside'
      tickPosition: 'outside'
      minorTickLength: 13
      tickLength: 15
      labels: 
        enabled: true
        formatter: -> labels[@value]
        style:
          'font-size': '20px'
          'color': '#00ff00'
     }
    ]
```

Comment: In Highcharts, yAxis can be an array of objects, that's probably why you can see curly bracket in question. I'm not expert in CoffeScript, but pretty experienced with Highcharts ;)

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example 2 objects.